# Sorting files in threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting

I have this program to sort the array of files via threads.
Here is my Sort class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Sort {

    /**
     * You are to implement this method. The method should invoke one or more
     * threads to read and sort the data from the collection of Files. The
     * method should return a sorted list of all of the String data contained in
     * the files.
     * 
     * @param files
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static String[] threadedSort(File[] files) throws IOException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(files.length);
        Future<String[]> value = null;
        String[] sortedData = null;
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length-1; i++) {
                final SortingThread worker = new SortingThread(files[i]);
                executor.submit(worker);
                value = executor.submit(new Callable<String[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public String[] call() {
                        return worker.getSortedData();
                    }
                });


            sortedData = value.get();
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedData.length-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(sortedData[i]);
        }
        return sortedData;
    }

    /**
     * Given an array of files, this method will return a sorted list of the
     * String data contained in each of the files.
     * 
     * @param files
     *            the files to be read
     * @return the sorted data
     * @throws IOException
     *             thrown if any errors occur reading the file
     */
    public static String[] sort(File[] files) throws IOException {

        String[] sortedData = new String[0];

        for (File file : files) {
            String[] data = getData(file);
            data = MergeSort.mergeSort(data);
            sortedData = MergeSort.merge(sortedData, data);
        }

        return sortedData;

    }

    /**
     * This method will read in the string data from the specified file and
     * return the data as an array of String objects.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            the file containing the String data
     * @return String array containing the String data
     * @throws IOException
     *             thrown if any errors occur reading the file
     */
    private static String[] getData(File file) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        // Read the data from the file until the end of file is reached
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                // the end of file was reached
                break;
            } else {
                data.add(line);
            }
        }

        // Close the input stream and return the data
        in.close();
        return data.toArray(new String[0]);

    }

    static class SortingThread implements Runnable {

        private File file;
        private String[] sortedData = new String[0];

        public SortingThread(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        public String[] getSortedData() {
            return sortedData;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String[] data = getData(file);
                data = MergeSort.mergeSort(data);
                sortedData = MergeSort.merge(sortedData, data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Merge Sort class:

```
public class MergeSort {

  // The mergeSort method returns a sorted copy of the
  // String objects contained in the String array data.
  /**
   * Sorts the String objects using the merge sort algorithm.
   * 
   * @param data the String objects to be sorted
   * @return the String objects sorted in ascending order
   */
  public static String[] mergeSort(String[] data) {

    if (data.length > 1) {
      String[] left = new String[data.length / 2];
      String[] right = new String[data.length - left.length];
      System.arraycopy(data, 0, left, 0, left.length);
      System.arraycopy(data, left.length, right, 0, right.length);

      left = mergeSort(left);
      right = mergeSort(right);

      return merge(left, right);

    }
    else {
      return data;
    }

  }

  /**
   * The merge method accepts two String arrays that are assumed
   * to be sorted in ascending order. The method will return a
   * sorted array of String objects containing all String objects
   * from the two input collections.
   * 
   * @param left a sorted collection of String objects
   * @param right a sorted collection of String objects
   * @return a sorted collection of String objects
   */
  public static String[] merge(String[] left, String[] right) {

    String[] data = new String[left.length + right.length];

    int lIndex = 0;
    int rIndex = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      if (lIndex == left.length) {
        data[i] = right[rIndex];
        rIndex++;
      }
      else if (rIndex == right.length) {
        data[i] = left[lIndex];
        lIndex++;
      }
      else if (left[lIndex].compareTo(right[rIndex]) < 0) {
        data[i] = left[lIndex];
        lIndex++;
      }
      else {
        data[i] = right[rIndex];
        rIndex++;
      }
    }

    return data;

  }

}
```

And here is my test class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * The class SortTest is used to test the threaded and non-threaded sort
 * methods. This program will call each method to sort the data contained in the
 * four test files. This program will then test the results to ensure that the
 * results are sorted in ascending order.
 * 
 * Simply run this program to verify that you have correctly implemented the
 * threaded sort method. The program will not verify if your sort uses threads,
 * but will verify if your implementation correctly sorted the data contained in
 * the four files.
 * 
 * There should be no reason to make modifications to this class.
 */
public class SortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            IllegalStateException {

        File[] files = { new File("res/file1.txt"), new File("res/file2.txt") };

        // Run Sort.sort on the files
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        String[] sortedData = Sort.sort(files);
        long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        double elapsedTime = (stopTime - startTime) / 1000000000.0;

        // Test to ensure the data is sorted
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedData.length - 1; i++) {
            if (sortedData[i].compareTo(sortedData[i + 1]) > 0) {
                System.out
                        .println("The data returned by Sort.sort is not sorted.");
                throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException(
                        "The data returned by Sort.sort is not sorted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The data returned by Sort.sort is sorted.");
        System.out.println("Sort.sort took " + elapsedTime
                + " seconds to read and sort the data.");

        // Run Sort.threadedSort on the files and test to ensure the data is
        // sorted
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        String[] threadSortedData = Sort.threadedSort(files);
        stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        double threadedElapsedTime = (stopTime - startTime) / 1000000000.0;

        // Test to ensure the data is sorted
        if (sortedData.length != threadSortedData.length) {
            System.out
                    .println("The data return by Sort.threadedSort is missing data");
            throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException(
                    "The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threadSortedData.length - 1; i++) {
            if (threadSortedData[i].compareTo(threadSortedData[i + 1]) > 0) {
                System.out
                        .println("The data return by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted");
                throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException(
                        "The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is sorted.");
        System.out.println("Sort.threadedSort took " + threadedElapsedTime
                + " seconds to read and sort the data.");

    }

}
```

I have implemented the threadedSort method using executor Services but i don't know why i'm geting this exception:

```
The data returned by Sort.sort is sorted.
Sort.sort took 0.003480673 seconds to read and sort the data.
The data return by Sort.threadedSort is missing data
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted
    at com.teamincredibles.threading.SortTest.main(SortTest.java:56)
```

I can't figure out what i've done wrong please review.
Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting result from your thread `SortingThread` so you should use `Callable` and not `Runnable` as:

```
        static class SortingThread implements Callable<String[]> {

        private File file;
        private String[] sortedData = new String[0];

        public SortingThread(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        public String[] getSortedData() {
            return sortedData;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] call() throws Exception {
            String[] data = getData(file);
            data = MergeSort.mergeSort(data);
            sortedData = MergeSort.merge(sortedData, data);
            return sortedData;
        }
    }
```

Now you can create tasks to submit to `ExecutorService` and get `Future<String[]>` as a result.

```
public static String[] threadedSort(File[] files) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(files.length);
        List<Future<String[]>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] sortedData = null;
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            futureList.add(executor.submit(new SortingThread(files[i])));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        for (Future<String[]> future :futureList) {
        String[] values = future.get();
        // merge values and  finalData to create one array.
      }
      return finalData;
    }
```

Also `5s` is a small time IMO. You can provide time of 1 day and if it finishes before that you will get the result else it will throw timeout exception.

I have suggested some changes which can at least provide you right direction. You can further explore various ways to improve your code. For example merging two arrays may be expensive and you can think about better option.

Comment: will using threads and callback like you sugested would be more effecient then simple sort method (without threads)?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed OP is using a `Runnable ` where as he should have used `Callable` as he expects result from his task. I have suggested him some changes which are part of standard Java practices. Whether this is more efficient than simple sort or not that OP needs to decide based on his requirements.

Comment: Please explain this comment: // merge values and  finalData to create one array.

what is finalData?

Comment: This is a task that OP needs to take care of. I believe OP should also put some efforts :)

Comment: sorry i'm quiet new to these services. What is OP?

Comment: ahahaha sorry i though its some service you're talking about. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77528/discussion-between-subhan-ahmed-and-akhil-mittal).

Answer (score 0):

Several issues.

---

```
for (int i=0; i<files.length-1; i++)
```

This will miss the last file.

---

For each file you

```
executor.submit(worker);
```

you then create a new `Callable` that gets the sorted data from the worker and returns it to you (why would you want to do that?).

You then wait for that `Callable` to finish (why would you want to do that?).

You then shut down the `Executor` (why would you want to do that?).

You then move on to the next file **all this for each file** (why would you want to do that?).

---

Probably more but I am losing the will to live. Get all of those issues sorted and let us know if the problem still remains.

Comment: What is the better and efficient way of doing it then?

Comment: Why it will miss the last file. (Yes its missing it)
What is the reason, what should i do to avoid it?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed - `for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)`